# Is the below design an abstract factory?

Tags: java

I have the following scenario

1. A method takes a vehicle type object and returns the following

   a. Road vehicle 
   b. water vehicle 
   c. flying vehicle.
2. another method takes the object returned from 1 and gives more specific object. For ex if "Road vehicle is returned" then this method will return Car, bus etc.

Can I say that this is an example of Abstract factory pattern? Because in step 1 , I am getting one of possible factory and in step 2, it is more of specific object.

Regards

Comment: This seems strange. You pass a type to a factory method, it creates an object. You then take that object, pass it to another factory method, and it creates a different object. Now you have two objects that seem to be in the same inheritance chain. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No yours is not an abstract factory, it is more of a ***Factory Method pattern***.

### Abstract Factory

> Abstract Factory offers the interface for creating a family of related
>   objects, without explicitly specifying their classes.

Something like this would be Abstract Factory

```
interface CarSparePartFactory{
    public SparkPlug createSparkPlug();
    public Wheel createWheel();

}

interface SparkPlug{

}

interface Wheel{

}
```

Here you are creating a group of related objects using an interface.

For more on Abstract factory:

- [What is abstract factory?](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html)

Answer (score 3):

You're not creating a concrete factory first, so I don't see this as being a representation of abstract factory. Thus you've got a concrete factory method.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have a Factory Method.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. An abstract factory should determine by itself the kind of object to be created. It's not supposed to be a parameter sent by the client. Otherwise, the main purpose of the abstract factory ("Provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.") is not satisfied.

See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern